# @XmlSeeAlso to point to child Exception classes

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, jax-ws, fault

The question is about Exceptions inheritance in JAX-WS.

```
@WebService(portName = "TestPort", serviceName = "Test", targetNamespace = "urn:Test", endpointInterface = "test.TestPort")
public class TestService extends TestPort {

    @Override
    public String test() throws TestException {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}

@XmlSeeAlso({MyException.class})
@WebFault
public class TestException extends Exception {

    public ServiceException() {
        super();
    }
}

@WebFault
public class MyException extends TestException {

    public MyException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I want MyException to be serialized and to be visible in WSDL but I still get default fault message for non-described exceptions exposing class and package name. I tried to use XmlSeeAlso to achieve this. But only 'throws' declaration of MyException seems to work.